# MariaDB Optimization - insert and select

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, insert

I have 2-3 php files.
I am sending sms to users by sending parameter in these php files. I'm checking the 3rd and 4th table before sending sms so select. If there is an id record, I do not insert. If there is no record with that id, I'm inserting. I check tables 3 and 4 for each insert operation. I can make 500-600 inserts at the same time. And I'm sending a parameter to a php file for each record. So the php file is running 500 times instant.

**This data is for testing purposes. It only works 20 times.**

I want to optimize my database. Do you have optimization suggestions for table structure or my.cnf file?

[image: Tablolarım]

My server:

```
CPU Model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3440 @ 2.53GHz
CPU Details: 8 Core (2527 MHz)
Ram: 32 GB
Centos 7
```

UPDATED:

My.cnf:

[mysqld]

```
performance_schema = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20GB
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_doublewrite = 0
event_scheduler = ON
max_connections = 500
long_query_time = 3
slow_query_log= 1
skip-name-resolve
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 4M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 48k
query_cache_size =300M
tmp_table_size = 1500M 
max_heap_table_size = 1500M


read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
join_buffer_size=512K
table_definition_cache=1000

innodb_lru_scan_depth=256

wait_timeout=60
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
skip-networking
sort_buffer_size=4M
log_error=/var/log/mysql_error.log
```

Mysqltuner:

```
    [--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.1.41-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err(0B)
[!!] Log file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err doesn't exist
[!!] Log file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.err isn't readable.

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 4M (Tables: 51)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 38M (Tables: 47)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 612 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 15d 21h 17m 25s (5M q [4.297 qps], 2M conn, TX: 870M, RX: 594M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 72% / 28%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 31.2G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 25.2G
[--] Other process memory: 428.6M
[--] Total buffers: 22.0G global + 5.5M per thread (500 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 459M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 22.7G (72.54% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 25.2G (80.59% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (5K/5M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 7% (35/500)
[!!] Aborted connections: 17.28%  (438978/2540869)
[--] Skipped name resolution test due to skip_networking=ON in system variables.
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 17.5% (195K cached / 1M selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 5K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 147503
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 6% (18K on disk / 299K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 80% (503K created / 2M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 30% (287 open / 934 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 4% (212/4K)
[!!] Table locks acquired immediately: 84%

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 459.8M
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 8 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.1.41-MariaDB)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Key buffer used: 100.0% (134M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/1.1G
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (269M cached / 74K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 92.1% (54M cached / 50M writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 20.0G/38.3M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 2.0G * 2/20.0G should be equal 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (722453016 hits/ 722453818 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 16.11% (57881 hits/ 359336 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 301455 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[!!] Aria pagecache hit rate: 93.9% (306K cached / 18K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: STATEMENT
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Reduce or eliminate unclosed connections and network issues
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Optimize queries and/or use InnoDB to reduce lock wait
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 4M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 512.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=20)
```

All status variables: Red fields

```
Created tmp disk 7.6 k  

Handler read 29.5 k 

Handler read rnd 47.9 M 

Innodb buffer pool 652  

Opened tables   556 

Select full join    13.2 k  

Table locks waited  396.9 k
```

A client is running a php file.
INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (...), (...), (...)
Other clients can run the php file at the same time. For example, there are 100 clients. The php file is running repeatedly for each client.
For example, we have 3 clients running at the same time.

```
1. The php file works for the client.

    INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (1), (..4.), (.'Sds' ..);

2. The php file works for the client.

    INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (.22.), (.2 ..), (.'qwe '..);

3. The php file works for the client.
    INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (.48.), (.6 ..), (.'ty '..);
```

**Currently, there are 120 clients and the CPU goes up to 70% instantly and back to 6%.**

UPDATED 2: I think it's 70% because of this query.

```
BEGIN
SELECT ss.car_route from persons p
inner join person_time ss on ss.comp_id =p.comp_id  
and ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')  AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i') AND ss.car_id=carid
and ss.day_ like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%') 
where (p.car_id=carid or p.back_car_id=carid ) LIMIT 1 into @route;
select sf.stop_hiz from car_comp sf 
inner join cars s on s.comp_id = sf.id and s.id=carid
into @hiz_stat;

if @route = 1 THEN

select ss.start_time,ss.finish_time ,p.id,p.name,r.photo, pp.status_ ,pp.time_per,ss.car_route,
ifnull(bh.id,0) AS called,
ifnull(mh.excuse_id,0) AS excuse_id,
ifnull(p.latitude_leave,0) AS latitude_leave,
ifnull(p.longitude_leave,0) AS longitude_leave,
ifnull(p.latitude_take,0) AS latitude_take,
ifnull(p.longitude_take,0) AS longitude_take,
case when (ifnull(p.call_notify,0)=1 or ifnull(p.sms_notify,0)=1) then 1 else 0 end AS call_notify ,
ifnull(p.row_num,0) AS row_num,
ifnull(p.take_phone,0) AS take_phone,
ifnull(p.leave_phone,0) AS leave_phone,
ifnull(p.back_row_num,0) AS back_row_num,
ifnull(ROUND(p.take_notify_meter/2),0) AS take_notify_meter,
ifnull(ROUND(p.leave_notify_meter/2),0) AS leave_notify_meter,
ifnull(p.latitude_notify_take,0) AS latitude_notify_take,
ifnull(p.longitude_notify_take,0) AS longitude_notify_take,
ifnull(p.latitude_notify_leave,0) AS latitude_notify_leave,
ifnull(p.longitude_notify_leave,0) AS longitude_notify_leave,
call_minute,
ifnull(ok.longi,0) as comp_longitude,
ifnull(ok.lati,0) as comp_latitude
from persons p
inner join person_time ss on ss.comp_id =p.comp_id and p.car_id=ss.car_id
and ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')  AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
and ss.day_ like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%')

LEFT JOIN notify_proc bh ON bh.table_id=p.id AND bh.car_route=@route
and bh.table_name='person' AND bh.notification_=4 AND bh.car_id=p.car_id and date_format(bh.date_,'%Y.%m.%d')=date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d')

left join  person_proc oh   on  pp.person_id=p.id
and pp.car_id=p.car_id
and date_format(pp.time_per,'%H:%i') >=ss.start_time
and date_format(pp.time_per,'%H:%i') <=ss.finish_time
AND pp.car_route= @route
and
pp.id in(select max(id) from person_procs
where date_format(time_per,'%Y.%m.%d')=date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d') and car_id = carid
GROUP by person_id
)
left join comp_way ok on p.comp_id = ok.id and p.car_id=carid
left join excuse_proc ep on mh.person_id=p.id and date_format(mh.time_per,'%Y.%m.%d') = date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d') and (mh.car_route=ss.car_route)
left join photo p on r.person_id = p.id and r.table_name = 'person'
where
(ss.car_route=p.car_u_route or p.car_u_route=3) and

p.car_id = carid and p.active_=1
AND p.work_time=ss.work_time
and @hiz_stat = 0;


else

select ss.start_time,ss.finish_time ,p.id,p.name,r.photo, pp.status_ ,pp.time_per,ss.car_route,
ifnull(bh.id,0) AS called,
ifnull(mh.excuse_id,0) AS excuse_id,
ifnull(p.latitude_leave,0) AS latitude_leave,
ifnull(p.longitude_leave,0) AS longitude_leave,
ifnull(p.latitude_take,0) AS latitude_take,
ifnull(p.longitude_take,0) AS longitude_take,
case when (ifnull(p.call_notify,0)=1 or ifnull(p.sms_notify,0)=1) then 1 else 0 end AS call_notify ,
ifnull(p.row_num,0) AS row_num,
ifnull(p.take_phone,0) AS take_phone,
ifnull(p.leave_phone,0) AS leave_phone,
ifnull(p.back_row_num,0) AS back_row_num,
ifnull(ROUND(p.take_notify_meter/2),0) AS take_notify_meter,
ifnull(ROUND(p.leave_notify_meter/2),0) AS leave_notify_meter,
ifnull(p.latitude_notify_take,0) AS latitude_notify_take,
ifnull(p.longitude_notify_take,0) AS longitude_notify_take,
ifnull(p.latitude_notify_leave,0) AS latitude_notify_leave,
ifnull(p.longitude_notify_leave,0) AS longitude_notify_leave,
call_minute,
ifnull(ok.longi,0) as comp_longitude,
ifnull(ok.lati,0) as comp_latitude
from persons p
inner join person_time ss on ss.comp_id =p.comp_id and p.back_car_id=ss.car_id
and ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')  AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
and ss.day_ like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%')
LEFT JOIN notify_proc bh ON bh.table_id=p.id AND bh.car_route=@route
and bh.table_name='person' AND bh.notification_=4 AND bh.car_id=p.back_car_id and date_format(bh.date_,'%Y.%m.%d')=date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d')
left join  person_proc oh   on  pp.person_id=p.id
and pp.car_id=p.back_car_id and pp.car_route=2
and date_format(pp.time_per,'%H:%i') >=ss.start_time
and date_format(pp.time_per,'%H:%i') <=ss.finish_time
AND pp.car_route= @route
and
pp.id in(select max(id) from person_procs
where date_format(time_per,'%Y.%m.%d')=date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d') and car_id = carid
GROUP by person_id
)
left join comp_way ok on p.comp_id = ok.id and p.car_id=carid
left join excuse_proc ep on mh.person_id=p.id and date_format(mh.time_per,'%Y.%m.%d') = date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d') and (mh.car_route=ss.car_route)
left join photo p on r.person_id = p.id and r.table_name = 'person'
where
(ss.car_route=p.car_u_route or p.car_u_route=3) and

p.back_car_id = carid and p.active_=1
AND p.work_time=ss.work_time
and @hiz_stat = 0;


END IF;

end
```

EDIT2:
[image: Monitor 2]

Comment: Let's see the actual queries.  Inserting 1 row per statement per transaction?  Or inserting 500 in a single statement?  Enable the slow log.

Comment: Slow log query is enable. [OK] Slow queries: 0% (15/1M)
And yes single statement.
This query runs separately with 500 different values. insert into table(id, a,b,c,d,e,f) values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) @RickJames

Comment: But does it look like `INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (...), (...), (...)`?  That would be inserting 3 rows in a single statement.  Your example showed only 1 row.

Comment: A client is running a php file.
`INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (...), (...), (...)`
Other clients can run the php file at the same time. For example, there are 100 clients. The php file is running repeatedly for each client.
For example, we have 3 clients running at the same time.
1. The php file works for the client.
`INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (1), (..4.), (.'Sds' ..);`
2. The php file works for the client.
`INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (.22.), (.2 ..), (.'qwe '..);`
3. The php file works for the client.
`INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (.48.), (.6 ..), (.'ty '..);` @RickJames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
max_connections=200  # from 1500 since max_used_connections was 18 to conserve RAM
thread_cache_size - REMOVE to allow default calc by MySQL and reduce threads_created
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8  # from 20 to reduce CPU cycles used for IBP mgmt
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
log_error=/var/log/mariadb/mysql_error.log  # from /var/log/mysql_error.log and it may work for you and avoid error message on MySQLTuner.pl report.
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answer. How can I default calc by MySQL and reduce threads_created? mysqltuner proposal for innodb_buffer_pool_instances 20. Why should I change it? I'm just asking to find out.

I don't know what innodb_lru_scan_depth does. I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: @mike  To allow MySQL to calc thread_cache_size either A) remove thread_cache_size from your config or B) lead the line with '# ' to disable recognition at instance startup. The overhead to manage 20 ibp_instances is much more than managing 8 ibp_instances.  Look at this url  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lru_scan_depth - to calculate the amount of work performed by the page cleaner thread each second.  Less scan_depth work is more time to do useful processing every second.

Comment: I tried all of them. Cpu 's sudden increases. The CPU was% 2 at a time for a single client. I added a photo. I updated post.

Comment: @mike Please add same style graphs in one hour for comparison to see if the spikes have settled down. Label the new ones with date/time above the graphs, please.

Comment: @mike Thanks for the new graphs.  It appears someone sent in about 35 KiB of data to be processed between 16:08:50 and 16:09:12.  By 16:09:34 this data had been 'processed' and the graph settled back down.  For additional assistance, view my profile, Network profile.  Slow Query Log analysis would likely be very helpful.

Comment: @mike Please consider using our FREE Utility Scripts to improve performance - findfragtables.sql will point you to the tables most in need of OPTIMIZE to reduce fragmentation and reduce READs required.  Thanks for the ACCEPT.

Comment: @mike Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
# cores of your MySQL Host server 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete current MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for current server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: "innodb_lru_scan_depth" was a game changer for me. I changed it from 1024 to 512 and Inserts into InnoDb database are almost double the fast. I will try to tweak this feature more but thanks to Your answer which just saved my app.

Comment: @Eryk-Wrobel,  innodb_lru_scan_depth of 100 will allow more useful processing to be completed every second.  That is the minimum at this time.  View my profile, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0   -- use 2 for speed; 1 for safety
max_connections = 1500     -- rather high
query_cache_size =300M     -- much too high; use 50M
tmp_table_size = 1500M       -- much too high; use 200M
max_heap_table_size = 1500M  -- much too high; use 200M
```

Generally, the Query cache is useless for Production machines.

`Created tmp disk 7.6 k` is useless without knowing either the `Uptime` (to gives tmp tables/second) or `Com_select` (to get % of queries).  It *probably* indicates either poor indexing or poorly written queries.  You have the slowlog turned on; what queries are interesting there?  (Use `pt-query-digest`)

Similarly, many of the `GLOBAL STATUS` values are useless without converting to "per second", etc.  For further analysis, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Scary, but it is just 'fake news':

> [!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 30.8G (98.43% of installed RAM)

It would be better to convert all tables to InnoDB.  Any references to "MyISAM is faster" is "old wives tales"; InnoDB has improved a lot over the years.

There should be little or no problem with having multiple clients each doing a multi-row `INSERT` at the "same time" to the same table.  But be sure to check for errors; deadlocks can happen in unexpected ways.

(From Update:)

```
max_connections=200   -- Yes, this is probably a better value 
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8   -- did it make any difference?
```

Is your test (multiple clients doing multiple-row `INSERTs`) a benchmark?  Or 'real' code?  I ask because 'benchmarks' rarely deliver the desired insight.

Is `autocommit` always `ON`?  Are you using any `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`?

It is unclear from your sample `INSERTs` what the relevance of "If there is an id record, I do not insert." is.  Please clarify.

> CPU goes up to 70% instantly and back to 6%.

The high number indicates a "slow" query (or burst of queries); the low number implies that such queries don't last very long.  Can you spot it in the slowlog?